# IntelliJ (Android Studio) Feature similar to IntelliSense Toggle Completion Mode in VS/SSMS

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

In Microsoft IDEs there's the option to Toggle the Completion Mode, which means that it will automatically select the top result if you click **.** (Dot) or **;**
Which is very intuitive and saves alot of clicks in the lifetime of the code writing process.

Is something similar possible in Android Studio ?

When I click Ctrl+Alt+Space it achieves exactly the desired result, but only for the currently typed expression, and then reverts to its old ways as soon as I move to the next line/expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings | Editor | General | Code Completion -> *Insert selected variant by typing dot, space, etc*.